# ¿Cómo hago para aplicar sobre imagenes, un modál realizado sobre un botón? Solo html y css

Tags: html, css, modal

Buenas tardes, tengo la siguiente duda, tengo actualmente funcionando un botón que despliega un modal, el cual incluye una imagen y texto. El botón era de prueba, ahora necesito que al hacer click sobre las imagenes que figuran en mi estructura html desplieguen lo que actualmente despliega este botón. Adjunto parte del código para que se entienda mejor. Sepan disculpar si no está bien expresado o citado el código, no estoy muy familiarizado con la programación como verán.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ActivaVentana" id="ActivaVentana"> 
<label for="ActivaVentana" id="AbreModal"> Abrir Modal</label> 
<label for="ActivaVentana" class="VentModal"> </label> 

<div class="contenidoventana"> 
<label for="ActivaVentana" id="CierraModal">X</label> 

<div class="texto-ventana">

<p>Este material tiene por objetivo colaborar en la labor diaria de los docentes, maestros y profesores. Las propuestas de trabajo que se incluyen pueden ser moldeadas de acuerdo a sus expectativas, su experiencia y a las características del grupo con el que trabajen. Se organiza de la siguiente manera: 

<br><br><br>
```

1. Una breve reseña histórico-teórica sobre el género de la novela gráfica, seguida de una serie de actividades sugeridas para comenzar a abordar las particularidades del imbricado vínculo entre texto e imagen. 
    
2. Actividades pensadas para trabajar el texto en sí mismo y la comprensión lectora que requiere ciertas habilidades indispensables para interpretar un relato. 
    
3. Propuestas de reescritura: habilidad para reconocer y dominar otros géneros discursivos, de modo tal que sean capaces de dominar los respectivos registros y léxicos de cada uno. 
    
4. Actividades interdisciplinarias que articulan el trabajo con otras materias, vinculando a alumnos y docentes en un proyecto creativo e innovador. Pueden servir de disparador para compartir espacios extracurriculares que permitan conceptualizar la lectura como actividad de (re)creación y exploración de nuevas miradas y modos de representar el mundo. 
    
Esperamos que este material sea de su agrado y que acompañe de manera fructífera su valiosa e inconmensurable labor educativa diaria.

#### La máquina del tiempo

```
<img src="imagenes/cuadernillos/maquinacuadernillo.jpg"> </div>
</div>
```

Este seria el botón. Y necesitaria aplicar su función a las imagenes escritas del siguiente modo y despues desaparecer ese botón, ya que solo era de prueba (solo es un fragmento del código:

```
<div class="tapas-todas">
<div class="libro">
<div class="tapita-1">
                <img src="imagenes/maquina.png"onmouseover="this.style.opacity=0.5" onmouseout="this.style.opacity=1"/>
                <br>
                <h2>La máquina del tiempo</h2>

</div>
<div class="tapita">
                <img src="imagenes/odisea.png"onmouseover="this.style.opacity=0.5" onmouseout="this.style.opacity=1"/>
                <br>
                <h2>La Odisea</h2>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que revises https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help para poder realizar una identación de código correcta, de esta forma estará mas ordenado tu código y sera mas fácil y rápido poder ayudarte.

Comment: También te falta código css, hay `div` sin cerrar y seria bueno que coloques la parte en donde declaras las clases(código css).

Comment: No veo por ningún lado el botón que nombras. Tampoco dónde declaras a la función. Tampoco entiendo porque has metido el enunciado del trabajo en mitad, ya que creo que no aporta nada al problema en cuestión. Por favor, redacta mejor tu pregunta e intenta realizar un ejemplo que podamos reproducir para ver como podemos ayudarte. Ahora no queda muy claro lo que quieres/tienes.

Comment: Gracias desde ya por su tiempo, adjunto un link de drive con la pagina subida, html, css y los links. 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Nb7Ktdg_tFF59Ee2so9YvSE_VGwo7n3W

Espero se pueda entender mejor. Desde ya muchas gracias por su tiempo

Answer (score 0):

Hola si lo entendido bien y lo que quieres es que una imagen haga la funcion de un boton, solo tienes que poner una etiqueta  con su correspondiente acción de un lado al otro de la imagen

```
<button data-target="#myModal"><img src="imagenes/cuadernillos/maquinacuadernillo.jpg"></button>
```

donde dice #myModal, cambialo por la id de tu modal.

Comment: Gracias @Berta, logré aplicar el boton a los titulos de las imagenes, ahora cada vez que hago click en alguno me despliega el modal. El problema es que por mas que le haya cambiado a cada uno su respectiva ruta de la imagen el titulo (Los que se visualizan adentro del modal) Siempre me muestra la primer obra que se ve en la lista). Tendré que hacer una clase o id para cada obra?

Con respecto a lo que me indicas, es eso lo que necesito, pero no logro que funcione aplicando el código q me pasas. Adjunto nuevamente: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Nb7Ktdg_tFF59Ee2so9YvSE_VGwo7n3W

Comment: No se si lo entiendo bien, pero si lo que quieres es abrir distintas modales para cada titulo, si, tendras que crear una id distinta para cada modal y cambiarle a cada una el data-target por la id de la modal que quieres abrir.

Comment: Claro, lo unico que se repite es el texto que aparece dentro del modal, pero cada libro tendria que mostrar su respectivo titulo e imagen adentro de su modal. Eso por un lado, y por el otro, lograr ese resultado haciendo clicks en los libros, de momento solo funciona haciendo click en los titulos, intente reemplazando #myModal por la id, pero lo unico q hace es agrandar la imagen y no me lleva a ningun @Berta

Comment: Actualmente tengo el código así, ya la imagen la converti en botón como me indicaste, y con css le saque las propiedades por defecto para que no se vea pero si se pueda interactuar. Sin embargo al hacer click no pasa nada, me podrias indicar que estoy poniendo mal @Berta

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Nb7Ktdg_tFF59Ee2so9YvSE_VGwo7n3W

Comment: La imagen no la tienes que convertir a boton, simplemente debes envolverla con una etiqueta boton. La imagen debe seguir siendo img

Comment: No lo tienes colgado en el servidor? tengo que guardar todos tus archivos en local para poderlo visualizar